# How to Stabilize VirtualBox in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: virtualbox, 19.10

All my virtualbox virtual machines were stable when Ubuntu 19.04 was the host. However, since upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 (which provides VirtualBox 6.0.14), each virtual machine crashes so frequently that I cannot practically use them.

Here are the specs of the host system:
[image]

Here's the command I use to install virtualbox:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Like I said, all my virtual machines were solid as a rock in Ubuntu 19.04. The only think I did was upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10, without changing any of their configurations, but now each virtual machine is unstable. They crash and reboot frequently with no warning. Also, since my laptop has 64GB of RAM, I give each virtual machine generous resources: max video memory that virtual box will allow an 8GB of RAM for each virtual machine.

What steps can I take to stabilize virtualbox in Ubuntu 19.10? For example, is there a stable PPA or some alternative way of installing it that will result in my "previously created virtual machines" running stable in Ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: We need more info. What version VB? What is unstable? How much memory have you allocated to your VM? Show me `free -h`.

Comment: Is it possible to rollback to the previous version of VirtualBox?

Comment: @heynnema: I updated my question to include versions. My host has 64GB of memory and I'm allocating 8GB to my Windows 10 vm. I also have an Ubuntu virtual machine, and a Windows XP vm. All crash frequently and I cannot find anything pertinent in the logs so far. The VMs just restart out of the blue. They all worked fine in Ubuntu 19.04, but are unstable in 19.10.

Comment: You can see differents ways to install VirtualBox of their website https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads but you should type virtualbox in a terminal to see errors when a VM crash.

Comment: Allocate 2 CPU and 2G RAM to your VM's. Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `free -h` and `ls -al /var/crash`. Run a memory test... Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: @jsb no reason to rollback VB

Comment: @JerareYoshi  The standard Ubuntu installation of VB works fine.

Comment: With a W10 VM, a Ubuntu VM, and a WXP VM... I have to ask... what is your host running?

Comment: Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to get your BIOS version, then go to the manufacturers web site and check if there's a newer BIOS for your computer make/model.